# Manifest unresolved class

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-lint

I need to recognize if in my android manifest is some removed class (for exmaple activity) and fail build. 
Class is red with text "Unresolved class..." but build is successful. 
Lint is also OK.

Is there any way to automatically detect this?

Comment: I could only think of writing a custom gradle task that would take the AndroidManifest.xml, parse it, read the android:name of each activity and check if the file exists. The task would execute before the build task. On the other hand, I don't see that big of a benefit in investing time in this, unless you remove dozens of activities on a daily basis.

Comment: Check `package` names in java-files.